# Kinetic JS Multi-Touch Scale Stage

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, zooming, kineticjs

I am using Kinetic JS on iPhone and Android.

I copied the example from

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-multi-touch-scale-stage-with-kineticjs/

to enable stage scaling and then I realized that when I zoom the zooming does not occur on the place where I pinch my zoom at, instead it happens at the top corner.

I also need to limit the zoom rate with a max/min zoom level, I believe this would help a lot.. thanks!

Code:

http://pastebin.com/cAgk2UiB

Modded Pinch Layer:

http://pastebin.com/mG1b75KK

Comment: setScale only resizes the objects/layers, you have to translate the positions yourself dependent on calculated coordinates of where you touch/pinch.

Comment: None of the links have a working solution. The Pastebin's have expired also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was taken care of by another developer who made a plugin. Try this out and see if it works for you

https://github.com/eduplus/pinchlayer

Comment: Yup I saw that! I tried but my page went blank think its some JS error, will check and will try again in a while. Thanks m8! :)!

Comment: The pinch layer wouldn't work on the latest KineticJS, and my codes wouldn't run well with the old KineticJS that PinchLayer is on, fixed it and its working well now :) thanks, now the issue is that I have 100+ circles and zooming is really slow on iPhone 4 and Android. any idea how I can improve on it?

Comment: not really, redrawing on mobile devices is costly. The thing to do would be to somehow define an area to redraw rather than the whole layer.

Comment: but doing a zooming will need to do a full redraw isn't it.. iphone 5 is quite snappy. iphone 4 is horrible. tried on my nexus 4 its horrible as well. haha.

Comment: Hi, I added those codes.. to pastebin that is. see my edit, thanks a lot. really appreciate it!.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated version of the tutorial: http://jsfiddle.net/9eaBq/

Just replace lines from 69 to 71 by this code:

```
var scale = {
  x: stage.scale().x * dist / lastDist,
  y: stage.scale().y * dist / lastDist
};
stage.scale(scale);
```

Working on an iPad (Chrome & Safari) under iOS7.